# changing RegEx from 3 digits to 4

Tags: regex

I'm not that great at RegEx, and have the following piece of code on my hands:

```
value.replace(/\s*.*(\d+[,\.]\d+)[^\d]*/m, "$1");
```

Now it works great at reducing this "\r\n\t\t\t\t& #36;0.05 USD\t\t\t" (please note I've intentionally left a space between the & and # as removing it converts it to a dollar sign on the site) to this "0.05". The issue I have is that if the number is a double digit (10.05 rather than 0.05) the expression removes the digit from the front and still outputs 0.05 rather than 10.05.

From what I can see in the expression, it's hard coded to pick up just 3 digits, so I was wondering if there's a way to amend it to also work in cases where there are 4 digits.

Comment: Your regex working fine see here http://rubular.com/r/O20VUoV8q0

Comment: Please, when editing this post stop putting a star quantifier after the first dot, and stop trying to escape the dot inside the character class. Neither of those elements existed in the original post. I've tried to fix it, but people keep changing it back. Both of those additions change the semantics of the regular expression, and invalidate answers that responded to the original regexp.  Plus, you dont escape dot inside character classes. It already has literal meaning there.

Comment: Btw, `[^\d]` is the same as `\D`.

Comment: If we're nitpicking the `[^\d]`, another sillyness is the /m flag, which has no effect since there regexp isn't anchored to start and/or end of line/string.

Comment: @DavidO I've reverted your edit, because it changed the expression.

Comment: `/\s*.(\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m` is the original... let's fix that and move on. ;)  I'll leave it to someone else to do.

Comment: @DavidO It's not the original, take a close look at the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example of the regex:

```
/\s*.*(\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m
```

And the data:

```
\r\n\t\t\t\t&#36;0.05 USD\t\t\t
\r\n\t\t\t\t&#36;10.05 USD\t\t\t
```

In the regex, the leading **`"/"`** (forward-slash), and the **`"/"`** before the **`"m"`** delimits the regex and is not part of the matching.

The **`"\s"`** in the regex is shorthand for **`[ \t\r\n\f]`** which matches whitespace (space, tab, Carriage-return, Line-feed, Form-feed). So, **`"\s*"`** will match **`"\r\n\t\t\t\t"`**

The **`"."`** (dot) in the regex matches any single character (generally any character except **`"\n"`**).

The **`"*"`** following the **`"."`** says to match any 0 ***or more*** characters. So, together the **`".*"`**, matches the **`"&#36;"`** (and possibly, additionally, one or more digits... see below).

Next, the **`"("`** in the regex starts the part of the regex that will "capture" part of your data.

The **`"\d"`** in the regex will match any 1 number. Actually **`"\d"`** matches [0-9] and other digit characters, like Eastern Arabic numerals **`"??????????"`**.

The **`"+"`** following the **`"\d"`** says to match any 1 ***or more*** numbers (digits).

The **`"[,.]"`** in the regex will match ***one*** of either a literal **`"."`** (dot), or a **`","`** (comma), to match the "decimal" separator.

Another **`"\d+"`** to match any 1 ***or more*** numbers (digits).

Next, the **`")"`** in the regex closes the part of the regex that will "capture" part of your data.

The **`"[^\d]"`** will match any 1 character that is ***not*** a number (digit). So, in this case, it will match the
**`" "`** (space).

The **`"m"`** at the end of the regex (following the second **`"/"`**): **`"m"`** changes the behavior of the **`"^"`** and **`"$"`** anchors, which are not used in your regex, so the **`"m"`** should have no effect. But, if you're using Ruby, **`"m"`** changes the behavior of the **`"."`** (dot).

Now, the "problem"... the **`".*"`** (before the **`"("`**), is in regex terms, "greedy". This means it will match as "early" as possible, and for as "long" as possible. So, if there is more than 1 digit following the **`";"`**, then the **`".*"`** will consume some digits.

Note: Using **`".*"`** can cause all sorts of problems, especially with **`"/m"`** under Ruby. It's best to avoid using **`".*"`** if possible.

There are 2 ways to fix this.

1) If the part before the number you want to capture is always **`"&#36;"`**, then specify that in regex instead of the **`".*"`**. So like this:

```
/\s*&#36;(\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m
```

or, if it will always be **`"&#36;"`** or something very similar to that:

```
/\s*[^;]+;(\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m
```

Here, **`"[^;]+;"`** means any string of 1 or more characters that does ***not*** contain a **`";"`** followed by a **`"[;]"`**.

2) If the part before the number you want to capture which is shown as **`"&#36;"`**, could be totally different in the data, then you just need to make sure that the part of the regex that is currently **`".*"`** will not match a digit in the last position. So like this:

```
/\s[^.,]*[^\d](\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m
```

Here, **`"[^.,]*[^\d]"`** means any string of 0 or more characters that does ***not*** contain a **`"."`** (dot) or a **`","`** (comma) where the last character does ***not*** contain a digit.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` after `/\s*` is matching the first digit if there are 2 or more digits. Remove that and see if it works...

```
value.replace(/\s*(\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m, "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   value.replace( /\s*.(\d+[,.]\d+)[^\d]/m, "$1");
```

## [WORKING REGEX](http://rubular.com/r/O20VUoV8q0)

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` matches **greedily** and therefore matches as many characters, including digits, as it can, as long as the rest of the pattern can still match.

The rest of the pattern can still match if just one digit is left for the `/d+` to match, so you only end up with one digit there.

If the semicolon in your example is always in that position in the strings you wish to match, use it as a marker like this

```
value.replace(/.*;(\d+[,\.]\d+).*/m, "$1");
```